# Difference between Torque and Speed

Tags: torque

Torque is the twisting force acting on a body while speed is revolution per minutes or seconds.

If I apply a twisting force on a ball with my hand ball will rotate. If I increase this twisting force on the ball it's speed will increase until the ball is balance. Then why is it said that torque is inversely proportional to the speed when in this case if I increase the twisting force the speed of rotation will increase not decrease?

Answer (score 1):

Torque is inversely proportional to speed *when power is constant*.  This is very useful when you have an engine with fixed power output.  As it spins faster, the torque it is able to produce is reduced.

As you spin the ball faster, your hand is simply unable to produce as much torque.  There will be a maximum speed your hand can go.  If the ball is moving at that speed, you cannot apply any additional torque at all.